# Angular mat-step change icon color

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to change the background color of the mat-step icon (angular material stepper) based on my array property : etape.etat.

```
    <div *ngFor="let etape of pro.etapes; let i=index">

      <mat-step *ngIf="etape.etat == 1" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <ng-template matStepLabel> {{ etape.nomEtape }} </ng-template>
      </mat-step>

      <mat-step *ngIf="etape.etat ==2" style="background-color: green;">
        <ng-template matStepLabel> {{ etape.nomEtape }} </ng-template>

      </mat-step>

      <mat-step *ngIf="etape.etat ==2" style="background-color: red;">
        <ng-template matStepLabel> {{ etape.nomEtape }} </ng-template>

      </mat-step>

    </div>
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

However, the background color is modified only using :

```
::ng-deep .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon{
  background-color: red; 
}
```

Is there any possibility to dynamically change the mat-step icon color based on a condition ?

Answer (score 0):

inside the **HTML**: Use [ngClass] and put your condition to set `classYellow` or `classGreen` or `classRed`;

inside the **TS**: manipulate the variables which go into the condition in your HTML

inside **CSS**: traverse from where you hae put the ngClass to `mat-step-icon` to set background color... something like:

```
::ng-deep .classYellow. mat-step-header .mat-step-icon{
  background-color: yellow; 
}
```

sample [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hedxgj)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the condition depends on the for loop. I could not put it in the mat-horizontal-stepper. I need to insert it into the mat-step.

Comment: @ghada Looking for the same thing, did u find a solution?